# OrientDB SQL join alternative

Tags: java, orientdb

I have the following database classes A,B,C with data and link fields:

1. A (some_data_A, linkB) - always exists
2. B (some_data_B) - always exists
3. C (some_data_C, linkA) - optional

C --> A --> B

Now I have to extract data from all 3 classes joined in 1 row. I can simple join B to A with:

```
select some_data_A, linkB.some_data_B from A
```

But can't figure out how to join fields C.some_data_C to each row using C.linkA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query

```
select some_data_A, linkB.some_data_B, $c.val1,$c.val2 from A 
let $c= (select val1,val2 from C where linkA=$parent.$current)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you start your query from C you can find all the data linked in your DB.
Is it helpful in your case ?

```
select some_data_C, linkA.some_data_A, linkA.linkB.some_data_B from C
```

[image]

Comment: Thank for reply, 
C.linkA can be null, so I miss those A that are not linked from C